# How to get (object) values when clicking on or hovering over bootstrap tagsinput tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I know that I can get all the (object) values by doing:
`$("input").tagsinput('items')`
as explained in the [Bootstrap tagsinput webpage](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

What I would like doing is getting a specific value when hovering over a tag.

The problem is that the hover event should be on the `span` element, while the values in the example seem to be recoverable from the `input` element only.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzbebhwt/) with the code. Scroll all the way down to see what's they type of event I would like to get the values from. For example, when hovering over 'Washington' I would like to see `{ "value": 4 , "text": "Washington"  , "continent": "America"   }`

Comment: You have a lot of rep points to ask a question without providing a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve show us your code.

Comment: Honestly I think the MCVE does not quite apply here, as it is a generic question, and not "about a problem caused by your(my) code". However, in case it will help people to understand the question as @mjw suggested, I was happy to provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Using the DOM inspector it looks like there is not much more "info" available on the span element that represents the tag, than its text content. So I think you'll have to go and use that up to look up the corresponding object in the tagsinput array ...

Comment: @CBroe Yep, the problem is that the text content could be repeated, so I should get the index of the clicked span. But I thought that there should be a simpler way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem. As @CBroe suggested, the idea is to get all the items from the input element, and then try to get the index of the element being hovered over.

```
$(".tag").hover(function() {
  //get all data items  
  var allTags = $("#inputTags").tagsinput('items');

  //get all tag elements
  var listOfChildren = Object.keys(this.parentElement.children)
  //find out which index I hovered over
  var tagIndex;      
  var that = this;
  listOfChildren.forEach(function(ee, ff) {
    if (that.parentElement.children[ee] == that)
      tagIndex = ff;
  });
  // get the corresponding data item
  var objectDataClicked = allTags[tagIndex];

  alert(objectDataClicked.value + '-' + objectDataClicked.text + '-' + objectDataClicked.continent)
})
```

You can find the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L60owyn2/3/)